# R loop replace multiple values in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, replace

does anyone know a more efficient way to do the following?  I have two matrices, one with integer values, the other with numeric.  I also have a list containing integer vectors.  I have a loop which sets the values of the numeric matrix to NA, when the integer values from the list are equal to the integer matrix.  Then I get the row product and sum from the resulting matrix. Is there a way to avoid creating a copy of the numeric matrix each step?  Or perhaps another approach all together? Thanks

```
mat1<-matrix(rpois(20*300000,6),20,300000)
mat2<-matrix(runif(20*300000),20,300000)
list1<-list(c(1,2,3),c(4,6),c(8,9,10,11))
results<-vector('numeric',length(list1))

start.time=Sys.time()
for(i in 1:length(list1)){
    copy<-mat2
    copy[mat1 %in% list1[[i]]]=NA
    results[i]=sum(apply(copy,2,prod,na.rm=T))
}
print(Sys.time()-start.time)
#
```

Comment: havent fully gone through your code, but just with a quick glance, it looks like `?outer` might be helpful for you

Comment: Are the numbers in `mat2` all positive as in your example? If that's the case, you could define `colProds <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) exp(colSums(log(x), na.rm = na.rm))` to take advantage of how `colSums` is much faster than `apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing your `apply` with `colSums` (assuming your numbers are positive, you'll need a bit more fiddling otherwise) gives me a close to 2x speed improvement:

```
for(i in 1:length(list1)){
    copy<-mat2
    copy[mat1 %in% list1[[i]]]=NA
    results[i]=sum(exp(colSums(log(copy), na.rm = T)))
}
```

Comment: They will always be positive, Thanks.